# Выделение текста с закругление по примеру в Flutter,Dart

Tags: flutter, textview, dart, dart-ui, flutter-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Как сделать такое выделение на Dart во Flutter (под Android, если кому важно).
Это пример скринов от Google на Kotlin, вот код  https://github.com/googlearchive/android-text/tree/master/RoundedBackground-Kotlin *
*Это просто текстовое окно TextView *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое во **Flutter** сделать достаточно легко с помощью `RichText` и `WidgetSpan` (альтернатива `TextSpan`, которую можно кастомить более гибко). Просто в `WidgetSpan` вы сделаете свой `Text` и обернете его в `Container`, который будет задавать нужный фон и границы для текста.

Написал вам пример экрана с подобным текстом, чтобы был понятен принцип, а вы уже под себя настроите по такому же принципу:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              WidgetSpan(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                  child: Text(
                    'Text highlighted',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              WidgetSpan(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                  child: Text(
                    'Text highlighted',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: А как искать и выделять найденное по среди текста? (недавно перешел на flutter)

Comment: @ChinHan а как вы бы выделяли вне флаттера? Можно тегами, парсить строку на WidgetSpan'ы и по тегам определять, выделять той или иной кусочек текста или нет.

Comment: на kotlin я искал по координатам и прорисовывал в нужном месте

Comment: @ChinHan думал вам надо по тексту выделять определенные фрагменты, можете тогда более подробно задачу описать? Вам надо выделять только текст на переносах строк вне зависимости от того, какой там текст? Тех.задача в таком духе? Нужно в общем подробнее мне понять проблему, тогда постараюсь помочь)

Comment: При вставке текста в текстовое поле берутся слова из базы данных и происходит поиск этих слов в тексте который вставили, потом те что были найдены выделяются в тексте (желательно с пересечениями : поездерева -в этом слове выделяется поезд и дерево с пересечениями, зачем, затем что есть языки в которых все слитно). Максимально понятно попытался объяснить. Спасибо ,что помогаете.

Comment: @ChinHan ух, с пересечениями тяжело будет)) нужно подумать будет, как можно было б реализовать подобное